# Which Sci-fi projectile weapons do not need a long barrel type shape?

Tags: science-based, weapons

As I am not well versed in science fiction or knowledge of guns, I have done some research recently into alien sci-fi guns as that is what I am currently designing and I find that many resemble human guns, even guns that have been designed to look very alien still have the human gun designs shapes, with a few exceptions.

The aspect of a gun of any kind whether it shoots bullets or energy types that give it the human look to me, is the long straight barrel, which is obviously a necessary part but I am wondering if any Sci-fi guns do not need a long straight barrel? Some energy types may not need a straight tube before the nozzle.

Which types of sci-fi guns that are possible in the future, do not need the traditional gun shape of a long straight barrel?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ussually scifi guns are shaped so readers/viewers will recognize them as guns.

Comment: Yep, humans would not be able to carry the battery pack of a laser gun actually

Comment: I'd say that the weapon can have the shape you want. Beyond looking for predictions for the far future (which is always an hazardous task), if your species of alien can't handle human-ergonomic weapons, they'll naturally develop other kinds :). Why not a cube-shaped handgun for robot aliens, with multiple barrels stacked in a square and ready to plug inside the arm ^^? The shape is technically not a long-barrel weapon anymore.

Comment: VTC: This is off-topic storybuilding, meaning you're asking about an aesthetic of your world and not a rule of your world. It's true that the shape of the gun can be a consequence of the technology used to build it, but you haven't asked about that (and you would need to spend the time to design that technology in terms of the rules of your world and only invoke us when you have specific issues you can't resolve). As written, any shape can be suggested and no best answer can be selected.

Comment: @Goodies Of course you mean humans *today* would be unable to carry a *useful* battery back built to *today's* technology. If you think the battery today needed to effectively power a hand-held laser weapon is large, you should consider what it would have been like 100 years ago... which suggests that 100 years from now humans just might carry such a battery without problems.

Comment: This is an open ended question. In your sci-fi future your guns can be any shape you want. Literally any shape will be equally valid, which makes this question inappropriate for this site.

Comment: I am not after shape suggestions, that is my work which I will happily design. PipperChip has given an example of an EM weapon not needing a barrel but with my limited knowledge, bullets, lasers and many other projectile weapons need a barrel to give a precise shot. I only want to find out what projectile types do not need this long barrel shape.

Comment: Questions asking for lists aren't really a good fit for this site. Consider though that guided projectiles don't need a long barrel to aim or stabilize them, though there may be issues of operator safety when shooting rockets...

Comment: Laser and sound/Wave base weapons do not need to have a barrel. A barrel is needed with projectile weapons that required to accelerate such projectile.

Comment: A long barrel serves two purposes:  To allow the projectile to be accelerated to higher speed by longer exposure to expanding gases,  and to improve accuracy by giving the bullet more spin stabilization and giving the user a longer distance for the sight picture between front and rear sights.   So use a self-propelled bullet like a Gyrojet, with self-stabilization and targeting,  and fire it from a device that allows you to designate the target before firing.  You can make that weapon look like anything you want.  The designator could be a reticle in AR glasses even.

Answer (score 2):

## *The Possibilities Are Innumerable*

The shapes a weapon (or "gun") can take *are* limited, but too numerous to give a big list. It depends on a lot of factors which sci-fi regularly tinkers with. Let's take a look at these limits.

## Limits on Weapons

Weapon design is limited by several factors, including but not limited to:

- biology of wielder
- biology/structure of the target
- energy sources (frequently chemical for most guns but potentially electrical and mechanical sources)
- environment (modern metal guns don't work well in space or on Venus by virtue of the environment)
- manufacturing technologies

And these can vary *wildly* throughout sci-fi! A 3-d printed gun looks different than a traditionally manufactured gun, and both (I bet) would look different from a gun *grown* from bacteria.

As an example, let's say your gun is held by a tentacled creature and produces damage against robots by directing some strong EM fields. In place of a long barrel, you may have an antenna, which can take various shapes, including a flat plate! Additionally, said tentacle creature may find a smooth ball with orthogonal rods sticking out of it more comfortable. So the creature presents a flat plate to the target while holding a spikey ball with their tentacle. This is not a traditional gun at all!

## The Universe Favors Certain Designs

Sometimes, physics just favors certain designs for certain tasks. The universe has rules and some things take better advantage of them. Ultimately, a gun needs to work, so humans here and aliens there may independently create very similar guns. (A parallel to this exists in biology: *convergent evolution*)

For example, barrels exist in IRL guns to stabilize and direct the bullet. The walls redirect the errant forces to the exit of the barrel. Likewise, the barrel constricts expanding gasses at to push the bullet forwards. Any gun which depends on expanding gasses to accelerate a projectile will, by virtue of physics, gravitate to a barrel.